# adding button to android application to quit app without using back button

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm  new to android programming,i want to add a button which exits the app.
but
i don't want to use the back buttons to exit the app

i have enough knowledge for creating intents to open new activity and other basics of android programming

Comment: i have started learning android programming from last 3-4 days,

Comment: You're looking for [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()). As an Android developer, the docs are ten times easier to find information rather than stack overflow

Comment: i dont have any idea about how to exit the app(except the back button)

Comment: you should not have a button to exit the app, it is against the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android guidelines, you should never ever put an Exit button on an Android application. You have to let the OS decide when to kill your Activity. You should look to the Android [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and implement any necessary callbacks.

Nevertheless, the previous answers work as well.

Answer (score 0):

use finish(); inside button click listener

Comment: I am sure @Emmanuel knew this answer but wanted the OP to do a little homework. Anyways, do add what he should do to avoid exit on back click.

Comment: What if he is not in an `Activity`?

Comment: where should  i add it in OnCreate or in the OnClick
?

Comment: thnx
it works

but when i check the logcat it shows the following error.

"03-20 22:17:54.133: E/Trace(618): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching this to button listener:
System.exit(0);

Comment: where should  i add it in OnCreate or in the OnClick
?

Comment: When you create button which you want to act as Exit button.
You attach onClickListener to it. 
Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

So in your case:

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         });

Comment: Consider choosing my answer as answered if that solved your problem completely.